# Getting 403 forbidden status through python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website content and getting 403 Forbidden status. I have tried solutions like using sessions for cookies and mocking browser through a 'User-Agent' header. Here is the code I have been using

```
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
}
page = session.get('https://www.sizeofficial.nl/product/zwart-new-balance-992/343646_sizenl/', headers = headers)
```

Note that this approach works on other websites, it is just this one which does not seem to work. I have even tried using other headers which my browser is sending them, and it does not seem to work. Another approach I have tried is to first create a session cookie and then pass that cookie to session.get, still doesn't work for me. Is it not allowed to scrape the website or am I still missing something?

I am using python 3.8 requests to achieve this purpose.

Comment: Using your script I get normal page. You're probably making too many requests in short timeframe and the server starts to limit you.

Comment: How do I know what should be the rate of requests? How long should I sleep before making a request? Is there a way I can try with a different port  / IP to spoof it (just to verify if it works)

Comment: You can try to use different proxy servers, for example and see if it works.

Comment: I tried adding ```proxies = {"https" : "https://10.10.1.11:1080"}``` to my session getter but it seems to timeout. Also that does not explain how am I able to still access the url through my browser

Comment: You can try to examine cookies that browser sends and cookies that sends `requests`. Maybe there' s difference

Comment: Yes thats seems sketchy , the cookie sent by the request is ```akavpau_VP1=1598088071~id=8c55d1275b4dc14c5ccb6569953ebae3; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None``` whereas the browser sends a different cookie. How were you able to run the same code to get a 200 ?

Comment: The cookie is probably set by javascript in the browser? You can try to copy the cookie from the browser to `requests` and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried using postman and copying the generated cookies to the code, but that does not help either :(